# How to determine if a printer exist?

Tags: c#, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do i check if a printer is installed and ready using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622903/how-do-i-check-if-a-printer-is-installed-and-ready-using-c)

i use [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) to make pdf files from my program in C#
while i have an Exception for general error, i want to know how i can check if the printer itself exist in the system.

something like the file exist check.

is there such an option?

Comment: This is answered in this post:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622903/how-do-i-check-if-a-printer-is-installed-and-ready-using-c][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622903/how-do-i-check-if-a-printer-is-installed-and-ready-using-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can know by using the PrintDialog

```
System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog dlg=new PrintDialog();
if(dlg.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
      MessageBox.Show("Printer Exist: "+ dlg.PrinterSettings.PrinterName);
else
      MessageBox.Show("Printer Does Not Exist");
```

Comment: Note: If the printer is on a server and you specify the UNC name to the printer on the server it's checking if the printer is valid on the server. It does not check if there is a queue on your computer pointing to that printer.

Comment: Alternately you can loop through the printers looking for the one you are interested in:  foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters) { ....}

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `PrinterSettings` class ([MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))
but, perhaps, even better would be to let the user locate the printer he wants to use by leveraging the `PrintDialog` class ([MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.aspx))