# Set file name in "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer using System.Print

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, xpsdocument, fixeddocument

I want to save an `IDocumentPaginatorSource`, e.g. `FixedDocument` or `XpsDocument`, as a PDF by using the virtual printer "Microsoft Print to PDF":

```
var printServer = new System.Printing.PrintServer();
var queue = printServer.GetPrintQueue("Microsoft Print to PDF");
var writer = System.Printing.PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(queue);
writer.Write(Document.DocumentPaginator); // Document = IDocumentPaginatorSource
```

This works, but makes the printer open a file save dialog. I would like to set the file name programmatically and either suppress this dialog completely or at least set the initial file name in the dialog. Is this possible?

I know, that this can be done when using `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument` by setting `PrinterSettings.PrintFileName` and `PrinterSettings.PrintToFile` (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36432772/469708), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47584111/469708)), but this is the old printing framework that does not support `IDocumentPaginatorSource`.

I checked all classes in the `System.Printing` namespace but did not find any way to set these two settings. Maybe it's possible to retrofit these seetings into the `PrintTicket` by [extending the print schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa970573(v=vs.100))? If so, how exactly would you do that?

Comment: I solved this a while ago without any 3rd party libraries, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58566537/1469494