# How to print flowDocument to PDF without specifying file name

Tags: c#, pdf, flowdocument, printdocument

I need to print a RTF to PDF in C# WPF.
My code currently uses `FlowDocument` because it's currently the best system I've found for printing an RTF.
I succeeded, but my ultimate goal is that the program can create the PDF without requiring the operator to enter the file name. It should be inserted automatically by the program.

```cs
// load RTF to FlowDocument
FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(flowDocument.ContentStart, flowDocument.ContentEnd);
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(rtfTempName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    textRange.Load(fileStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
}
// Assign Microsoft Printer for PDF output
PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
var printers = new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueues();
var selectedPrinter = printers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Microsoft Print to PDF");
if (selectedPrinter == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Printer not found!");
    return;
}
// setting selected Microsoft PDF printer
printDialog.PrintQueue = selectedPrinter; 
printDialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
// ??? Is it possible to setting something like "filename=..." ???
// ??? and "PrintToFile = true" ???

// Print document
printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "Label");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically set filename and path in Microsoft Print to PDF printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985624/programmatically-set-filename-and-path-in-microsoft-print-to-pdf-printer)

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. I had seen this post, but they don't start from FlowDocument.

Comment: Look closely at the answer I linked above, it uses the same PrintDialog as you I think, which contains a  [PrinterSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.printdialog.printersettings?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-windows-forms-printdialog-printersettings]) property, which in turn has a [PrintFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printfilename?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-drawing-printing-printersettings-printfilename) property.

Comment: I think "PrinterSettings" property not is present in WPF